# What is object in the GRANT <permission> in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view, sql-grant

What could be  `[ OBJECT :: ][ schema_name ]. object_name` in the

```
GRANT <permission> [ ,...n ] ON 
        [ OBJECT :: ][ schema_name ]. object_name [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ]
        TO <database_principal> [ ,...n ] 
        [ WITH GRANT OPTION ]
        [ AS <database_principal> ]
```

Could it be a table or view?

Comment: I guess a table or view or database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OBJECT here refers to any of the things that exist in sys.objects. From the [documentation for sys.objects](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324.aspx), that could be any of

- AGGREGATE_FUNCTION
- CHECK_CONSTRAINT
- CLR_SCALAR_FUNCTION
- CLR_STORED_PROCEDURE
- CLR_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
- CLR_TRIGGER
- DEFAULT_CONSTRAINT
- EXTENDED_STORED_PROCEDURE
- FOREIGN_KEY_CONSTRAINT
- INTERNAL_TABLE
- PLAN_GUIDE
- PRIMARY_KEY_CONSTRAINT
- REPLICATION_FILTER_PROCEDURE
- RULE
- SEQUENCE_OBJECT
- SERVICE_QUEUE
- SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
- SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION
- SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE
- SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION
- SQL_TRIGGER
- SYNONYM
- SYSTEM_TABLE
- TABLE_TYPE
- UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT
- USER_TABLE
- VIEW

Mind you, not every permission makes sense for every type of object. For instance, you can't grant execute permission to a table. Indeed, not every object type can be the target of a grant (primary keys, for instance). The [documentation for grant](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx) has a nice list near the bottom of each type of securable and link to a documentation page for what permissions can be granted to it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you're asking, but the `OBJECT ::` keyword here isn't meant to be replaced by some sort of identifier such as `TABLE ::`, it's meant to be specified literally as `OBJECT ::`. It's used to indicate that you want to grant permissions to an object as opposed to, say, a schema. According to [this page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188371.aspx), an object is any schema-level securable, such as a table, view, stored procedure, sequence, etc.

Also according to that page, the `OBJECT ::` keyword is optional if `schema_name` is specified. That leads me to believe that the need for specifying `OBJECT ::` is simply to make sure the database it's what type of entity the permissions are being granted to, since permissions can be granted to objects, schemas, server principles, and more.

Comment: So in the sql statement grant execute ON foo.Addresses TO newAddresses - foo.Addresses is a table?

Comment: There's no way to know that without more information. `GRANT` statements aren't specific to tables, only to schema-level objects. It could be a table, a view, a sequence, or many other types of objects. If what you're after is a way to infer the database schema from these `GRANT` statements, I'm afraid that's not enough to go on.